# How to list the files with content that are in azure repo using REST API

Tags: azure, azure-rest-api, azure-devops-services

I am referring this link.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/items/get?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0

I require assistance in forming the api link for the below scenario.

List all the files (with content) that are in a particular repo with .yml extension.

Please assist

Answer (score 0):

The only way to **Get the list of Files** available in Azure Repo is **Rest API** call. For this we have to use the **PowerShell**.

#### [List All Repos](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/repositories/list?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1#examples)

Used to retrieve the Repos

```cs
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/git/repositories?api-version=5.1

# With Optional Parameter
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/git/repositories?includeLinks={includeLinks}&includeAllUrls={includeAllUrls}&includeHidden={includeHidden}&api-version=5.1
```

#### [Get Files](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/items/get?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1#download)

It Get the content of Single item. **Download** parameter is used to check whether we can download the content or not.

```cs
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/git/repositories/{repositoryId}/items?path={path}&api-version=5.1

# With Optional Parameter
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/git/repositories/{repositoryId}/items?path={path}&scopePath={scopePath}&recursionLevel={recursionLevel}&includeContentMetadata={includeContentMetadata}&latestProcessedChange={latestProcessedChange}&download={download}&$format={$format}&versionDescriptor.versionOptions={versionDescriptor.versionOptions}&versionDescriptor.version={versionDescriptor.version}&versionDescriptor.versionType={versionDescriptor.versionType}&includeContent={includeContent}&resolveLfs={resolveLfs}&api-version=5.1
```

You can implement above Api in your PowerShell accordingly. Refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70246265/15997690) for how to implement this in PowerShell.